# ReactJS.net on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm hoping I'm able to get some help out there with people with more experience on ReactJS than me. I'm using MVC 5 with ReactJS (using ReactJS.net to take care of the translation from JSX to js) and I was able to some stuff done that works pretty well. Testing the my code on my local pc works fine for debugging, but once I publish it to Azure for testing I get this error:

GET http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/jsx/FriendSelect.jsx?_=1429662139230 404 (Not Found)

This is usually the error I get when the jsx file doesn't get converted to js successfully. Does anyone know the steps I need to take to get ReactJS.net to work properly on Azure?

Comment: It's definitely doable, I've seen a few people do it (one user was using Azure websites for benchmarking pooling of JS engines). Can you check the error log for any errors? Do you know which version of IIS it's using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to use anything react.net etc...? React comes with a JSXTransformer file which transforms your JSX to JS while you're in the process of developing your site.  Compiled and minified JS code should be used in production once you no longer need JSX.   Tools like Gulp can assist with automatically minifying your code for you.

Whether the site is Azure, Linux Ubuntu or anything else it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Chris, I agree with what you are saying. Once the files are converted/complied there shouldn't be an issue and that's why I was trying to use ReactJS.NET instead of Gulp.

Comment: I'm tested my configuration on other servers running IIS 7 and IIS 8 and the app works ok, ReactJS.net does it's work just fine. The problem seems to be specific to the Azure environment.

Comment: Chris, the reason I use React.Net is because it allows you to create bundles. You bundle up JSX files along with js files and you don't have to worry about minifying web.optimization takes care of that for you.

Comment: ah okay, I think Babel is a very popular tool that has this ability as well.  I typically use that to watch directories, transpile JSX and minify.